# MFTF(magento2): [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService

Tags: magento2, mftf, selenium, api-functional-tests

I am trying to hit the command {vendor/bin/mftf run:test AdminLoginSuccessfulTest} for mftf functional testing but I get this error :-
Test  tests/functional/Magento/_generated/default/AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest.php:AdminLoginSuccessfulTest

[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException] Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: 'cspc296', ip: '19*.1**.*1.**', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.13.0-39-generic', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Comment: Are you running in Ubuntu machine or WSL ?

Comment: sir its running in on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Do you have selenium set up, running and accessible? Here's my `dev/tests/acceptance/.env`:

```
MAGENTO_BASE_URL=https://www.mysite.local/
MAGENTO_BACKEND_NAME=admin_ij75ex
MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME=johnd
MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD=********
SELENIUM_CLOSE_ALL_SESSIONS=true
BROWSER=chrome
MODULE_ALLOWLIST=Magento_Framework
BROWSER_LOG_BLOCKLIST=other
ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION=7
MAGENTO_BACKEND_BASE_URL=https://www.mysite.local/
SELENIUM_HOST=selenium
SELENIUM_PORT=4444
SELENIUM_PROTOCOL=http
SELENIUM_PATH=/
```

Here's the selenium container setup from my docker-compose:

```
selenium:
    container_name: selenium
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.3.0-20220628
    environment:
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=5
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
    extra_hosts:
     - "www.mysite.local:172.17.0.1"
    ports:
     - 4444:4444
```